# Encoding issue of Polish characters

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

I have a data frame containing character vectors. The data I used is a web scraping output of a particular website gathered during previous year within different computers (PC). Operational system probably was the same (Windows). After I combined all pieces together into single data frame I found, that after applying of `gsub` function for instance (`str_replace` causes same issue) cause an encoding distortion, so that some of Polish characters become wrongly encoded (Figure and system specification of PC presented below). **voivodeshipRaw** is a raw\original data, while **voivodeshipProcessed** is a character vector after applying `gsub()` (I tried to remove unusual spaces “\s+”). I applied `Encoding` and `stri_enc_detect` to detect encoding. The output presented in columns: **encodingType** and **stri_enc_detect**. As you might see output differs. Cells with encoding distortions (column **voivodeshipProcessed** id: 4, 7, 1946505 and 1946507) have **unknown** encoding based on `Encoding` function and **windows-1250** based on `stri_enc_detect`. I tried to change encoding of such cells using following functions:

```
stri_enc_toutf8 = stri_enc_toutf8(str = voivodeshipRaw)

encoding = sapply(voivodeshipRaw, function(x){
      Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
      return(x)
      })

iconv = iconv(voivodeshipRaw, from = "windows-1250", to = "utf-8")
```

The output presented in Figure below. A you might see distortions still exist.

`charToRaw()` output for **voivodeshipRaw** column in figure below (raw data, śląskie voivodeship, id: 1946504 and 1946505) without and with an encoding issue:

```
# id: 1946504 -> proper encoding
c5 9b 6c c4 85 73 6b 69 65

# id: 1946505 -> wrong encoding
9c 6c b9 73 6b 69 65
```

**My question** is how could I avoid such encoding distortions after applying `gsub`, `str` or `stri` functions?

**Figure**
[image]

System specification:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    
system code page: 1251
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: no guarantees but perhaps you could try adjusting the Locale so that LC_CTYPE = Polish_Poland.utf8 rather than Polish_Poland.1250 ?

Comment: Switch to R 4.2. [R 4.2.0 on Windows came with a significant improvement. It uses UTF-8 as the native encoding…](https://blog.r-project.org/2022/06/16/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2.1-on-windows/). No problems since I did it…